# What does --branch do in Push command?

Tags: mercurial

```
-b --branch BRANCH [+]     a specific branch you would like to push
```

I've seen many people suggesting the use of -b but I don't understand why, what is it that disturbs them.

Could any one post an example of what would be pushed to the repo with and without `--branch` option? People says that avoid sending ALL THE BRANCHES but I dont understand it.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `hg push` command does is calculates the difference between what revisions receiver has, and what revisions sender has.

By specifying `--branch` it will filter out only changesets that belong to a given branch.

That's it: only changeset that belong to it will be pushed, and other local changesets will not be.

Comment: So you  are saying that if I cloned a repo with 2 additional branches, hotfix1 and hotfix2, then I modify something in the first then another thing on the second, and I push my change made in the second, when standing on that brach, it will send modifications on hitfix1 too?

Comment: @Jorge: I'm not sure what you mean. The key does exactly what it states: only changesets from the given branch will be sent (with minor exclusions, but it doesn't matter in this case)

Comment: @Jorge: yes, if you edit in both branches and do a plain `hg push` without `-b`, the changes in both branches will be pushed to the remote repo.